# Truncated File While Compiling Android

Tags: android, makefile, compiler-errors, truncated, dragonboard

I'm currently trying to compile Android 2.3 Gingerbread for my APQ8060 Dragonboard on Fedora 19. Everything's been set up, following [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development) guide, and I've run into a few errors prior, but those were fixed using a few fixes from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/2EwtWQTqjdI/eBl1bK-KNM8J). Now, however, I'm running into an error with a truncated file, and Google isn't turning up anything. Here's what gets put out to the terminal:

```
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/create_test_dmtrace
host Prebuilt: cts (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/cts_intermediates/cts)
host SharedLib: libssl (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libssl.so)
out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libcrypto.so: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libssl.so] Error 1
```

It should be noted that I'm not using the standard Android source code, instead using the one provided by the board's manufacturer. I believe it's modified slightly to better work with the board.